# LiDAR Feature extraction specifications/standards

Tags: vector, lidar, standards, feature-extraction

I have vector data representing forests/trees/buildings that have been automatically extracted from LiDAR data.  I am looking for specification/guidance for LiDAR derived products, or any standard for defining these features.  For example, a forest is only a forest if it is larger than x square meters, or a tree is not a tree unless it is x meters tall, etc.  The automatic process has created detailed features, and as a result very large datasets.  I would like to find a standard definition so that I can thin the datasets.  Ideally, I would like to know if there are standards developed/adhered to by the USGS, USDA, NGA, NFS, etc.  Does anyone know of such standards/specifications?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Process is similar to [this](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/4/3/762).

Answer (score 2):

These are reserved definitions used in the [LAS File Format Exchange v 1.4 R13](http://www.asprs.org/Committee-General/LASer-LAS-File-Format-Exchange-Activities.html). Each lidar vendor has proprietary classification algorithms for assigning these classes and there are, unfortunately, no associated standards or specifications. The USGS was headed down this road but CLICK no no longer funded.